# Error a el ejecutar un proyecto en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar mi proyecto, sea en el emulador o en el dispositivo, me aparece este error. me pueden ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"Error"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No vemos el error completo, podrías editar tu pregunta y pegar ahí el error.  Algo así: \`\`\`{error}\`\`\`

Comment: Eso es todo el error?, podrías hacer lo que te pedí en mi comentario anterior, sin imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Tu Android Studio esta configurado con la función de Ejecución instantánea (`Instant Run`), esto se puede ver en el error mostrado en la imagen.

```
/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk resources/debug/
```

Una opción es eliminar los directorios `/build` de tu proyecto y este se generará nuevamente.

Pero lo mejor sería desactivar "Instant Run", ve a la configuración en "Build, Excecution, Deployment" > "Instant Run".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]